# Expo Media Library permissions error on Android [React Native]

Tags: android, react-native, expo, android-permissions

Hi I'm working on a react native app and I'm using expo-media-library to get user's photos but, only on android, when I try to ask for permissions using the following command I get the status as never_ask_again even if it's the first time I'm asking for permissions and I don't event refuse them because the popup didn't show up.

```
MediaLibrary.requestPermissionsAsync()
```

Then I tried to manually give permissions to the app, through settings, but when expo try to access to media library, here's the error that occurs.

```
Error: Missing MEDIA_LIBRARY permissions.
```

I also tried to use `react-native-permissions` to ask for permissions, but the result is the same.

Maybe someone has had this problem before and can help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

=> Do you add this in your manifest file or not..?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

const permission = await Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
  if (permission.status !== 'granted') {
      const newPermission = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
      if (newPermission.status === 'granted') {
        //its granted.
      }
  } else {
   ....your code
  }
```

Comment: Yes, I have added them.

Comment: @PaulRock i have edited my answer please check it and let me know.

Comment: Thank you for your time Ankit, but I find out that the problem is related to the version of the android project, since I'm using a special combination of react-native-navigation/wix and expo-modules. When I updated it the error disappear.